# wpf charts: plot time in X-axis and double values in Y axis for line graph

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, linechart, datavisualization.toolkit

I need to plot data on a graph having time values in seconds and double values. time values are in format ranging from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 with interval of 00:01:00. The time values are continuous. And other values are discontinuous and range from 0.00 to 200.00 with interval of 10.00.
Now I am able to plot graph having time in X-axis and double values in Y-axis.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Title="Testing.." >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          IndependentValueBinding="{Binding time}"
                          DependentValueBinding="{Binding value}">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis
                Orientation="X" />
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But the requirement is 90degree rotated effect. i.e, time values should be in Y-axis and double values should be in X-axis still having the graph plotted as "double values plotted as function of time values".

In the above code If I just change the orientation of independent axis to "Y", I am getting exception.

Comment: I doubt that such line charts exist. If you want values on the X-axis, you had better choose the Bar chart.

Comment: @vorrtex: Ok.. But requirement is line chart only. So isn't there any workaround for that? If i change "Layout transform" with a "rotation transform" of angle 90, I get the "time axis" on left and "value axis" on top. But I need "value axis" on bottom. So any such suggestions??

Comment: The only one way to do this is to download the source code of the charts toolkit and implement your own class.